# I can't open .py files in Finder after updating my mac to 10.15 Catalina

Tags: python-3.7, macos-catalina, finder

I have updated mac os to Catalina, and now in Finder I can't open my python files with double click.

I usually use IDLE for python 3.7.9. The default application to open  .py files is already set to IDLE (3.7.9) but when I double click on my file, nothing is happening.

But it's work if my IDLE isn't opened.
I've trying to open with Thonny and it's same: it's doesn't work if Thonny ist opened and it's work if Thonny is not opened.

I can open my files with:
`$ idle -e file.py` in Terminal or `$ env PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin idle myfile.py`

I have only IDLE 3.7.9 and reinstalled (I have deleted other versions)

Answer (score 0):

IDLE on Mac right now can only files when the IDLE shell is open. Just open the IDLE application and you'll be able to open .py files. Or you can maybe upgrade your python or Mac.

Comment: In fact, it's quite the opposite for me, when IDLE is open, the files no longer want to open. Which breaks a problem if I have to shut down the app every time to open .py files on finder.

Comment: IDLE isn't always a good choice for a Python IDE, maybe consider switching to visual studio code, sublime text, or pycharm instead